# Определить увелечение высоты div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html5

Привет. У меня есть div contenteditable с стилями:

```
min-height:85px; height:auto
```

Что означает, что данный элемент при содержимом больше чем 85px будет увеличиваться в высоту. А так как содержимое абсолютно динамическое и формируется в процессе работы с элементом, то необходимо отследить момент увеличения данного div contenteditable. Я пробовал метод: onresize - событие не срабатывает. Далее я попробовал по onkeyup отслеживать нажатие enter. Но в данном случаи я слишком поздно отслеживаю увелечение - уже после того как текстовое поле увеличилось. Если использовать onkeydown - то тут нужно определить а будет ли после нажатия enter увелечение текстового поля? Поэтому пришла идея просматривать высоту содержимого, но из-за min-height, любая высота в js даётся как 85px, а не по факту занятого пространства.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А такой вариант подойдет?

```js
class TextFieldValidator {
  static isResizeXValid( prevRectangle, currentRectangle ){
    return prevRectangle.width !== currentRectangle.width;
  }
  static isResizeYValid( prevRectangle, currentRectangle ){
    return prevRectangle.height !== currentRectangle.height;
  }
  static isResizeValid( prevRectangle, currentRectangle ){
    return TextFieldValidator.isResizeXValid( prevRectangle, currentRectangle ) ||
      TextFieldValidator.isResizeYValid( prevRectangle, currentRectangle );
  }
}
class TextField {
  constructor( element ){
    this.element = element;
    this.inputHander = event => this.element_inputHandler( event );
    this.element.addEventListener( 'input', this.inputHander );
    this.rectangle = {
      width: NaN,
      height: NaN,
      
      top: NaN,
      left: NaN
    };
    this.setRectangle( this.element.getBoundingClientRect() );
  }
  
  element_inputHandler( { target } ){
    let rectangle = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    if( TextFieldValidator.isResizeValid( this.rectangle, rectangle ) ){
      // если мы тут, то произошел ресайз
      
      console.log( 'resize' );
    }
    
    this.setRectangle( rectangle );
  }
  
  setRectangle( { width, height, top, left } ){
    this.rectangle.width = width;
    this.rectangle.height = height;
    this.rectangle.top = top;
    this.rectangle.left = left;
  }
}

let textField = new TextField( document.body.querySelector('#textfield') );
```

```html
<div id="textfield" contenteditable="true">some text</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Такой вариант не подойдёт, потому что я использую уже готовый с кучей наворотов contenteditable. И если делать с нуля его - то будут проблем очень много, нужно такое решение которое можно приделать к любому коду

Comment: Получается что Вы заведомо спросили фигню чтобы просто послушать варианты, которые Вам в любом случаи не подойдут, так как Вы используете что-то кастомное? Вы так развлекаетесь?

Comment: Нет, я спрашиваю варианты как выйти из ситуации. Вы понимаете, что чтобы нормально такой div работал нужно около 200 строчек кода? и если начинать разрабатывать что то своё - это затянется. Вы предложили просто готовый код, а я ждал что мне подскажут инструмент или идею, а в этом коде для меня многое не понятно. Допустим я придумал так что при нажатии на символ копировать всё содержимое в обычный невидимый div и проверять уже его высоту, в нём нет min-height, потому можно легко узнать точную высоту уже. Вот мне хотелось бы услышать что то лучше такого решения, а не переписывание уже готовых ве